# Adjust brightness on screen without hardware buttons

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, raspberry-pi, brightness

I have a small [Waveshare 7' Touch Screen LCD](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)) connected to my Windows 10 PC via HDMI. The screen is very bright by default. According to [this document](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/56/PWM_control_backlight_manual.pdf), soldering is required in order to access the screen's backlight setting.

Is there any other way to control the screen's brightness? I'm thinking of software that overlays a semi-transparent gray tint on this screen only (similar to the Windows Night Light feature). The color of my other two screens should not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
with a script such as:

```
intensity:=50 ; just a number
Gui, 1: Default
Gui, Color, 0x000000 ; Color to black
Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +E0x20 ; Click through GUI always on top.
WinSet, Transparent, %Intensity% ; Set intensity first based on the time of dday
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w%A_ScreenWidth% h%A_ScreenHeight% ; Cover entire screen
```

This will create click-through window on the primary screen, located
in the x,y coordinates of 0,0 and covers the entire screen with a transparency factor
of 50%.
By changing the displayed coordinates you may choose another monitor,
which is just part of the extended desktop with its coordinates of X, Y,
width and height.

To discover the coordinates of your monitor, use the
[SysGet command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm).

You will need to study AutoHotkey, but you may find a lot of information available
on the Internet.

Once you know something about AutoHotkey, you may tackle
the AutoHotkey script
[SmartBright](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73190-smartbright-custom-screen-brightness-and-eyesaver/).
This script lets you control brightness using the mousewheel control, by
holding down the left button mouse while scrolling up or down.
As above, it adds a black overlay over the screen of varying transparency.

Comment: Fantastic. I think I've even used this functionality a decade ago.